# How is the periscope port on Soyuz spacecraft secured for the atmospheric reentry?

Tags: crewed-spaceflight, reentry, safety, soyuz-spacecraft

Soyuz Backup Periscope (ВСК-4) is used in Soyuz spacecraft to align itself for orbital corrections, deorbit burn, and rendezvous with the International Space Station. Here is a cute closeup photograph of one such unit:

[image]

<sup>NASA's *poultrynaut* Camilla looks through the Soyuz Backup Periscope (ВСК-4) used to align the Soyuz spacecraft. (Image: [SDO](http://sdo.gsfc.nasa.gov/))</sup>

And its function is nicely explained by ESA astronaut [Samantha Cristoforetti](http://www.esa.int/Our_Activities/Human_Spaceflight/Astronauts/Samantha_Cristoforetti) in one of her [logbook entries on Google+](https://plus.google.com/photos/+SamanthaCristoforetti/albums/5955004512408861265/5955004522705378658?pid=5955004522705378658&oid=112628950566484266163):

> Most of the time the view of interest is the one "straight out" along
>   the axis of the periscope. Whenever there is a need to fire the
>   engines, the reference orientation in which the Soyuz puts itself is
>   along the local vertical: in this orientation the periscope faces
>   towards Earth. The optical setup is such that the commander sitting in
>   the center seat will see the entire globe symmetrically in the field
>   of view if the Soyuz is properly oriented. Also, any feature on the
>   surface of the Earth will be running from top to bottom (or from
>   bottom to top if it's a braking attitude).
>
> When we approach the Station for rendez-vous the mirror is turned so
>   that the commander can now have a forward view. This is the view we
>   would use to align the Soyuz manually if we had to fly a manual
>   docking.
>
> [image: Soyuz periscope]
>
> Quote and photograph source: [Samantha Cristoforetti on Google+](https://plus.google.com/+SamanthaCristoforetti/posts), image credit: NASA

But this periscope is a part of the landing module (the middle section of the Soyuz vehicle) and the periscope doesn't seem to retract into the module at all, so...

**Is this Soyuz Backup Periscope (ВСК-4) disposed of after the deorbit burn and before the atmospheric reentry, when the crew landing module separates from utility and instrument-assembly modules of the Soyuz spacecraft, and if it is, how is the remaining gap in the landing module's external hull sealed / secured to thermally insulate the capsule for the reentry?**

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Regarding the jettisoning of the periscope check out [this simulation in the video explaining Soyuz reentry sequence at 9:40.](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-l7MM9yoxII#t=9m34s)

You'll notice the periscope being jettisoned at the same time the spacecraft propulsion and orbital modules separate from the landing capsule.

I think what left is just a small window of heatproof transparent material. In the same video @11:40 you can see the main windows are not covered during re-entry, so it is not a problem. The plasma just burns the outside layer of the window.