# Is there an equivalent of the Dragon 'claw' and Apollo umbilical fairing between the Soyuz crew and service modules?

Tags: spacecraft, reentry, soyuz-spacecraft, mechanisms, service-utilities

The Apollo service module provided power etc. to the command module through umbilical connections covered by a fairing.  When the two modules were separated, a 'guillotine' cut through the cables and the fairing opened.  It can be seen at the top of this Apollo 13 image from Wikipedia:

[image: Apollo 13 Service Module]

The Dragon 1 and 2 (uncrewed and crewed respectively) have a similar device called the 'claw', between the trunk and the crew module (visible in the centre of this Wikipedia image):

[image]

During the recent re-entry of demo flight 2, the claw was mentioned as part of the trunk separation procedure.

I believe the purpose of these devices is to avoid routing cables through the heatshield.  I've never noticed a similar connection between the corresponding Soyuz modules, is there such a thing or are services supplied in another way?

Comment: "Dragon 1 and 2 (uncrewed and crewed respectively)" 
Note that dragon 2 exists in both crewed and uncrewed configurations. So far we've only had a crewed and a dummy-crewed mission, but the next CRS resupply will be on an uncrewed Dragon 2

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is an "intermodule umbilical" that is "shed" at module separation.

> In preparation for the split of the modules, external cable lines
> connecting the three main sections of the spacecraft and the six
> petals of the thermal protection layers on the Descent Module, SA, are
> shed. The Habitation Module is then depressurized, while the crew
> members in the Descent Module close the visors on their helmets.

It is not under a fairing, because the Soyuz itself is under a fairing at launch.

Image of the umbilical:

[image]

Image source: [NASA](https://www.nasa.gov/sites/default/files/thumbnails/image/iss035-e-034210_0.jpg), cropped and annotated by me

There's a schematic showing that the indicated feature is the umbilical [here](https://qph.fs.quoracdn.net/main-qimg-7bbe7090acb0ca1feef296241f3fa0e6). I did not embed the image because of the copyright notation on it.

This schematic from the [Soyuz Crew Operations Manual](https://www.infosondas.com/2017/04/pdf-soyuz-crew-operations-manual-soycomrop-19final/) shows that the umbilical connections do not pass through the lower heatshield.

[image]

This still from a ESA video linked at this [answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/3233/6944) shows the split umbilical at module separation.

[image]

This image from [wikipedia](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/ba/Soyuz_TMA-03M_capsule_shortly_after_landing_%28201207010015HQ%29.jpg/1280px-Soyuz_TMA-03M_capsule_shortly_after_landing_%28201207010015HQ%29.jpg), cropped and annotated by me, shows the umbilical panel after landing.

[image]

Sources

- [Mir Hardware Heritage](https://spaceflight.nasa.gov/history/shuttle-mir/references/documents/mirheritage.pdf) p.13
- [Russian Space Web - Soyuz Landing](http://www.russianspaceweb.com/soyuz-landing.html)